# Is there any other way to run .htaccess file on the local server?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there any way to run the `.htaccess` file on the local server without being online?

Comment: Could you enlarge the description of your question?

Comment: normally we are using .htaccess file in server for some other purpose.  If the file using in local server means it won't work.  Is it possible to run the file in local server and get output of online?

Comment: Can you please explain the whole scene? without using .htaccess file in your explanations, because it seems far away from your real needs. What's the initial task? You have an offline server and want to have some information from online one? "offline" means "no connection to the net". with no connection to the network, you cannot get information from the network, regardless of any config file or other tool. So, your question seems senseless and desperately need more detailed explanations of your needs.

Comment: If your question is "is it possible to use .htaccess file on the local(offline) server", the answer is simple: yes, it is possible. Is it possible to have a copy of some online server on some offline server? Yes, it is possible if you can transfer online server's data to the offline one.

Comment: If by 'local' you mean a local file you loaded in your browser, check my answer. If by 'local' you mean 'the copy of apache running on the system in front of me not serving pages on the public internet', then ignore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not much detail in your question, but let me try an angle that hasn't been taken yet (as far as I noticed).

If you're asking why the **.htaccess file works for this request**:

```
http://myserver.com/mypage
```

Or even **this request**:

```
http://localhost/mypage
```

But **not this request**:

```
file://www/mypage
```

It's because the first two are actual HTTP requests, requiring the page to be 'served' by Apache. Apache (assuming a correct configuration for your situation) processes the .htaccess file while serving the request.

That whole process is bypassed for the third 'request', because that's not a HTTP request, that's a **local filesystem** request. In that case the web browser is loading a file much like a word processor. No web server is ever contacted, so the .htaccess file is meaningless.

If that's what you mean by **local**, then **to my knowledge there's no way to get a browser to process the .htaccess file for a local request**.

But in the future, there's a world of difference between requesting a flie for a local server, and loading a file from a local system.

Again, this is only my take on one way your question could be interpreted, if indeed you're referring to requesting the file from a local web serve - check the configuration as many have suggested. (*And check that you're running Apache too*.)

Answer (score 7):

`.htaccess` file is never being "run". It is merely a configuration file. An unnecessary one, as each of its commands can be used in the main `httpd.conf` configuration file.

What is the background that led you to this question?

To enable this file, the `AllowOverride All` setting in the `httpd.conf` file must be set.

Comment: to add to this.  If you access to your server's httpd.conf, you can simply put the contents of your .htacces into your <Directory> tag and set AllowOverride None for a slight performance boost.

Comment: It depends on the kind of stuff one would allow external .htaccess files to do. It could be something different from AllowOverride All, setting options as the httpd.conf (or apache2.conf) says in the comments...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question, but yes, you can use `.htaccess` files in any Apache installation, whether that Apache runs on the internet or locally.

Comment: Yes apache only, run on locally not in internet.  Is it possible?

Comment: @karthikeyan yes. See www.xampp.org for easy installation packages.

Comment: @karth there is no difference between "internet" and "local" calls

Comment: If i using the .htaccess files in internet and local, in internet it working fine but in local i cannot get display the page.  Why it is ? anything i have to do with internal local server or any configuration is there ?

Comment: @karthi please update your question with the source code of the .htaccess and what you just said.

Comment: If by 'local' you mean you're using file:/// URLs, then no, .htaccess will be useless to you, as you're not actually using Apache.

Answer (score 1):

A .htaccess file is a means to configure a webserver on the fly, and without needing access to the global configuration files.

Since all it does is configure a *server*, it doesn't make sense for it to be involved without there being networking (even if only localhost to localhost networking) involved.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess files are not considered when running php from the command line because Apache isn't called.  But, as long as you are making a web request through Apache, and you have AllowOverrides configured properly for that directory, the .htaccess should be read and used by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any .htaccess file in any Apache instance regardless of platform. A service on a server is still a service on a server irrespective whether it is accessed on a local network (or even the same machine) or via a wider network (i.e. the Internet).

Answer (score 0):

Set `AllowOverride All` in the configration file and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the setting in your config file, if you do not want online access do not forward port 80 to your server, if you do want online access then do forward port 80.

Answer (score 0):

If it means running on Windows .htaccess, use [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and change the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to have the same domain as the web server. Then test it locally.